# Ubuntu: Screen resolution doesn't fit size of monitor (Vmware)

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-player

I have just installed ubunto in Vmware Player and it works great, but all of the resolutions it gives me there isn't one to fill the entire screen.

I was scouting around the net and found this,

```
- Open up VMWare, don't boot up Windows yet.
- Go to "View" and select "Autofit window" and "Autofit Guest".
- Close VMWare.
- Go to the terminal and do:
sudo gedit ~/vmware/preferences
- Now where it says:
pref.autoFitFullScreen = "fitHostToGuest"
change it to:
pref.autoFitFullScreen = "fitGuestToHost"
```

but when i do it the preferences file is empty

Can anyone tell me where it is??

Totally lost

**edit**

I have installed VMtools...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The preference file is located on your host computer NOT in your VM!**

Location on a Windows host:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\VMware\preferences.ini
```

Location on a Linux host:

```
~/vmware/preferences/preferences
```

Answer (score 3):

I tested that, when Windows is guest OS, but may work with other OS too:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install VMWare tools in order for your VM to make use of your screen resolution.

Follow this [guide/tutorial](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/Installing_VMware_Tools_with_VMware_Player.html) in order to install it on vmware player.

Comment: Guide is ancient!

Comment: @mlissner well it would be ancient due to the time the question was answered.