# Making VMPlayer actually scale to full screen

Tags: virtualization, resolution, vmware-player

I'm trying to use VMware Player 4.0 to play my existing virtual machines (previously created using VMware Workstation, to which I don't have access anymore).

All works fine, but when the guest OS changes resolution to something like 320x200, I get a tiny rectangle in the center of my screen, which is unusable, because everything is so small and I can barely read text. My host OS screen resolution is 1600x900.

That applies both to windowed mode and "full-screen" mode, which isn't actually a full screen mode.

**How can I force the tiny guest screen to be actually scaled to fit my physical screen?**

It's occured to me that I could make my host OS resoultion much smaler before launching the player, and that would probably work, but it'd mess my desktop icons up.

I've also tried [`fitHostToGuest` and `fitGuestToHost`](https://superuser.com/questions/300134/ubuntu-screen-resolution-doesnt-fit-size-of-monitor-vmware), to no avail.

The guest OS is either Windiows XP or Windows 98SE (I have two VMs).
The host OS is Windows 7.