# How do I get full screen in Mint Linux under VMware player?

Tags: linux, display, linux-mint, vmware-player

I just installed VMware player and Mint Linux; however, only a small portion of the VMware window is used. I want Linux to take up the entire screen. How do I change this? In Linux I tried going to menu->displays but nothing happens (I think the window may be opening off screen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're missing VMWare Tools, an application that is installed on the guest OS, and allows communication back to the VMWare environment so that you can go full screen, and copy files from the guest to the host (and vice versa).

Warning: It can be a pain to install VMWare Tools on an OS is not supported.

Here is a [video on installing VMware tools](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U8mnEg7nEw) on Mint Linux.

Otherwise you need to change the screen resolution for your Linux install.  [See here for instructions](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/877).

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had installed VMware tools but I didn't do it properly, I didn't know you had to run the file from the command line using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

On the menus of VMWare Player / Workstation:

View >> Autosize >> Auto-fit Guest

View >> Autosize >> Auto-fit Window

See screenshot at:
[Ubuntu: Screen resolution doesn't fit size of monitor (Vmware)](https://superuser.com/questions/300134/ubuntu-screen-resolution-doesnt-fit-size-of-monitor-vmware)

Comment: Are these options? Are they located in a menu bar? How are they accessed? The answer as it stands has no context, which makes it difficult to evaluate.